# Is a simple graph the "sum" of a partial order and its dual?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, order-theory

A "$n$-order matrix" $T\in M_n(\mathbb F_2)$ is a matrix such that there exists a partial ordered relation $\leq_T\subset [1,n]^2$ such that :

$T_{ij}=1\Leftrightarrow i\leq_T j$

(where $T_{ij}$ is the $i,j$ coefficient of $T$)

A  "$n$-graph matrix" $S\in M_n(\mathbb F_2)$ is a symmetric matrix such that $S_{ii}=0$ for all $i\in [1,n]$

(where $G^t$ is the transposed matrix of $G$)

> Is it true that for any "$n$-graph matrix" $S$ there exists a "$n$-order matrix" $T$ s.t. $S=T+T^t$ ?

Comment: Presumably you want also to require that your $S$ have $0$ entries along the diagonal.

Comment: Of course, thank you LSpice! (I'm editing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even with $0$'s on the diagonal it's still false. Consider the matrix $S = \left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0&0&1\cr 1&0&1&0&0\cr 0&1&0&1&0\cr 0&0&1&0&1\cr 1&0&0&1&0\end{matrix}\right]$. Suppose $S = T + T^t$ for some order matrix $T$. Then this order must have either $1 < 2$ or $2 < 1$ since $s_{12} = 1$. Wlog say $1 < 2$. Similarly we must have $2 < 3$ or $3 < 2$.

Suppose $2 < 3$. Then $1 <2 < 3$, and hence $t_{13} = 1$, but $s_{13} = 0$ so this implies that $t_{31} = 1$, i.e., $3 < 1$. If a "partial order" is antisymmetric this is impossible, but even if you allow $1 < 3 < 1$ we then get $2 < 3 < 1$, so that $t_{12} = t_{21} = 1$ and this contradicts $s_{12} = 1$. So $2 < 3$ is impossible.

We have shown that $1 < 2$ implies $3 < 2$, and similarly $2 > 3$ implies $4 > 3$, and then $3 < 4$ implies $5 < 4$.

But what is the relation between $1$ and $5$? Since $s_{15} = 1$ we need either $1 < 5$ or $5 < 1$. Wlog say $1 < 5$. Then $1 < 5 < 4$ so $t_{14} = 1$, but since $s_{14}= 0$ this forces $t_{41} = 1$, i.e., $4 < 1$. Again this contradicts antisymmetry, but even if you drop antisymmetry it forces $5 < 4 < 1$ so that $t_{51} = t_{15} = 1$ and this contradicts $s_{15} = 1$. So $S = T + T^t$ is impossible.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice counterexample with very elegant  smart  proof. You also shown that it is still a counterexample for "pre-order" not only "partial order"!! thank you!

Comment: I modified the hypothesies and  ask a new question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306560/decomposition-of-a-graph-according-to-some-order

Comment: The essence of this example is that $S$ is the matrix of $C_5$ (the $5$-cycle), and $C_5$ is not a comparability graph (not even perfect).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a counting argument showing that almost all $n$-graph matrices are counterexamples.

There are $2^{(1/2+o(1))\cdot n^2}$ graphs on $n$ vertices, but only $2^{(1/4+o(1))\cdot n^2}$ partial orders on $n$ elements; see these papers by  Kleitman and Rothschild:

[Asymptotic enumeration of partial orders on a finite set](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-205-00/S0002-9947-1975-0369090-9/)

[The number of finite topologies](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-02/S0002-9939-1970-0253944-9/)

The main reason for the separation is that the Hasse diagram is triangle-free, and there are only $2^{(1/4+o(1))\cdot n^2}$ triangle-free graphs on $n$ vertices (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8123 for references).

Comment: I wrote the first attempt to weakening hypothesis after reading your very instructive and nice answer! This answer suggests that we might try to get $S=T+T'$ with $S$ equal to a graph matrix "up to a permutations" (i.e of permutation of rows and a permutation of columns) , and $T$ and $T'$ equal to an order matrix "up to permutations" ...(but  maybe it would'nt be a nice or interesting statement to make after all...)

Comment: Anyway I think it's wrong too, because $T+T'$ is almost never symmetric up to right and left permutations matrix product, fora  random couple $(T,T')$...

Comment: This is a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others, the answer is no. In fact, the graphs that can be obtained this way are exactly the [Comparability Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph). This graph class is very well studied and well understood. It is also a subclass of perfect graphs, which are known to not allowing any induced off cycle with at least 5 vertices (such as the one in Nik Weaver's answer). Hence, any graph that consists of an odd cycle (or contains one as induced subgraph) cannot be obtained this way.