# Is a simple graph matrix the sum of a "shiftordered" matrix and its transposed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, order-theory

This is the generalization of a question [Is a simple graph the "sum" of a partial order and its dual?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306557/is-a-simple-graph-the-sum-of-a-partial-order-and-its-dual)

Nik Weaver  found a counterexample in a very nice, complete (and instantaneous!) answer,  so I modify the question to hope for a yes.

(I changed the old $S$ of previous question in $G$ in this question )

A  "$n$-graph matrix" $G\in M_n(\mathbb F_2)$ is a symmetric matrix such that $G_{ii}=0$ for all $i\in [1,n]$

A "$n$-order matrix" $T\in M_n(\mathbb F_2)$ is a matrix such that there exists a partial ordered relation $\leq_T\subset [1,n]^2$ such that :

$T_{ij}=1\Leftrightarrow i\leq_T j$

Let's add  $m\in \mathbb N$ full zero **first** rows and $m$ full zero **last** columns to an $n$-order matrix then we will call it a $(m+n)$-schiftordered matrix. (since $m$ can be $0$, an ordered matrix is a schiftordered matrix)

> Is it true that for any "$n$-graph matrix" $G$ there exists a "$n$-schiftordered  matrix" $Z$ s.t. $G=Z+Z^t$ ?

(Note that if $S$ is the one that occures in Nik Weaver answer then $Z$ defined by  $Z_{ij}=S_{ij}$ if $i>j$ and $0$ if not, satisfies $Z+Z^t=S$ and $Z$ is a $5$ -shiftordered matrix)

Comment: The time I spent trying to parse the mis-spelled original title surely would have similarly consumed waaaay too much mental energy from other people, too! So had to repair it... :)

Comment: It seems that essentially the same counting argument applies as the one for the previous question (https://mathoverflow.net/q/306562).

Comment: That's true!! Can you please put it as an answer! Then I could accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanded comment:
It seems that essentially the same counting argument applies as the one for the previous question (mathoverflow.net/q/306562):

We can make first $m$ rows and last $m$ columns of an $n\times n$ matrix zero in $n+1$ different ways, this increases the total number of matrices $S$ at most $(n+1)$ times.